# Is there a way to search for user defined strings in different outlook attachments using python?

Tags: python, full-text-search, ms-office

Currently i am working on a project where i have to extract attachments and e-mails from outlook and check whether a user defined string present in them or not. I've completed the extraction part but still searching for a way to search for text/string within the attached documents. Is there a way to this by using python?

Comment: What type of output attachments are we talking about? Under which format did you extract them?

Comment: I am talking about different documents that are attached with e-mail like .pptx, .docx., xlsx, .pdf, etc. I have not converted their format, just extracted from emails using python's pywin32 library and `.SaveAsFile` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Microsoft Office files you can:

1. Automate Office applications.
2. Use the [open xml SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) if you deal with open XML documents only.
3. Use third-party libraries for dealing with documents.

It is up to you which way is to choose.